# Idiomatic template parameter pack wrapper for template parameter pack deduction disambiguation

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

My initial goal is to disambiguate the following:

```cpp
template<typename... T, typename... U>
void foo(){}
```

In that case, `foo< <a_sequence_of_types> >()` always results in `T = <a_sequence_of_types>` and `U = <empty_parameter_pack>`.

A classic solution is to pack `T...` and `U...` in `std::tuple<T...>` and `std::tuple<U...>` respectively and use these types as default arguments in foo.

```cpp
template<typename... T, typename... U>
void foo(std::tuple<T...>, std::tuple<U...>){}
```

Problems arise if any of the involved template parameters is not default constructible as it is becomes impossible to bind the dummy parameters of foo in that case.

Then I started looking for a standard, idiomatic template parameter pack wrapper without luck. A false hope was `std::index_sequence_for` that does not enable template parameter pack deduction as it is only a template alias for `std::integer_sequence` that erases its template *type* parameter pack.

I ended up using my own wrapper

```cpp
template<typename... T>
struct TypePack{};

template<typename... T, typename... U>
void foo(TypePack<T...>, TypePack<U...>){}
```

which is trivially constexpr default constructible and works like a charm in place of std::tuple. But it lacks the clarity that standard types provide when used in an idiomatic way. Is there any such *more idiomatic way*?

---

**NOTE:** This is part of the implementation of my code base and is not visible from the end user. Please do not tackle that question under the angle of API design. I am more interested in self-documenting code at that point.

Comment: Not in the standard, but in boost we have `boost::mpl::list` if that works for you.

Comment: I don't think it lacks clarity. You could even use two different pack names: `foo(FooLHS<T...>, FooRHS<U...>)`

Comment: The best way to ask for design of template is by providing examples of usage with all corner cases possibly with expected code to be generated. Your question is so abstract that it is impossible to tell you if your approach to some problem is correct.

Comment: @Nelfeal, Good point. Relying on the wrapper type name to provide extra context could be a strong point in favor of your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problems arise if any of the involved template parameters is not default constructible as it is becomes impossible to bind the dummy parameters of foo in that case.

You can pass [`std::type_identity<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) instead of `T` to tuple to pass type:

```
foo(std::tuple<std::type_identity<int&>,
               std::type_identity<const float&>>{},
    std::tuple<std::type_identity<void>>{});
```

Another possibility is to break `foo` in 2 parts:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct foo_t
{
   template <typename... Us>
   static void foo() {/*...*/}
};
```

with usage similar to

```
foo_t<int&, const float&>::foo<void>();
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have specified c++17 but its always nice to get a sneak peek into c++20. In any case, I would consider std::tuple + std::type_identity to be more of a STL-only workaround considering how verbose it is compared to introducing an extra type. Also I'm not sure it can be considered idiomatic at the time of writing ;)
I had thought about the class template + template member function solution but I felt it was too complex for the job. I keep it as a joker for more convoluted situations.
Considering the options, I think that I'll stick to my solution.

Comment: `TypePack`/`type_list` is a good alternative and probably the cleanest IMO. I think the problem is not so common to have an idiomatic solution ;-)